# Conditional Formatting filling in merged cells using text (Excel 2013)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

So, the issue I am running into is conditional formatted merged cells. Right now I am able to get part of the answer with using =$k2="False" but that does not get all the cells I want to be filled in. It just gets the cells linked to that cell. However, I cannot get the 2 rows underneath filled. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.[Excel Doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfL4j.png)

Comment: Could you provide a more clear description of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, because merge cells only display the first cell, other merged cells is display as blank:
[image]

It seems like a by design behavior for Conditional Formatting with merge cells.

Comment: Interesting idea about the blanks. Hmm maybe I could used that. I'll give that a try and see where it goes.